# Python ElementTree find not working

Tags: python, elementtree

I am new to ElementTree. I'm trying to snag the `<sid>` value from an XML response.

The following code is not working for me. How do I extract the value in `<sid>` ? I am not sure where the number `53` is coming from here.

```
    ...
    r = requests.post(self.dispatchurl, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.passwd))
    print r.content
    tree = ET.ElementTree(r.content)
    print tree.find('sid')
```

output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/myuser/PycharmProjects/autoshun/shunlibs/SplunkSearch.py
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>super__awesome__search__searchname_at_1489433276_24700</sid>
</response>

53

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This number is *the position at which the first occurrence of `"sid"`starts in the string*. That should be a comment as, to be honest, I don't know how to get the value in `<sid>` because I don't have any experience with `ElementTree`.

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP is almost 2 years old, however I came across the same issue and found the solution that worked for me. What worked was removing the namespace right after the parse call which loads the XML file.

A function like this:

```
def remove_namespace(xmldoc, namespace):
    ns = u'{%s}' % namespace
    nsl = len(ns)
    for elem in xmldoc.getiterator():
        if elem.tag.startswith(ns):
            elem.tag = elem.tag[nsl:]
```

I have discovered that ElementTree has issues with namespaces, you either strip them out using a function like the one above, or you have to pass the explicit namespace to the find or findall functions.

Answer (score 1):

the following code worked for me:

```
    r = requests.post(self.dispatchurl, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.passwd), stream=True)
    root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
    for i in root.iter('response'):
        print i.find('sid').text
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use xpath.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xml = '''\
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <response>
...     <sid>super__awesome__search__searchname_at_1489433276_24700</sid>
... </response>
... '''
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> for sid in root.iterfind('.//sid'):
...     sid.text
... 
'super__awesome__search__searchname_at_1489433276_24700'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on the comment to use namespace, I printed out the element in question which is typically in the format `<Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse' at 0x7f4e9409c590>`. Using this namespace, I was able to perform the `find()` via `responseXml.find('{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}SiteHostedPictureDetails').find('{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}FullURL').text`. The reference used was https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces